# How to copy Gradle caches to another offline machine?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, offline-caching

I've got two Ubuntu 16.04 machines. One is connected to the Internet, while the other one is fully offline. I'd like to build an Android project on the offline machine. On the online machine, it builds successfully. So, I've copied the entire `.gradle` to the offline machine and run build process with `--offline` flag. Surprisingly it fails. Lots of

```
No cached version of ....
```

I suspect it's because of the hash algorithm used to generate hash for each `.jar`, `.pom`, etc. I think hashes are different from one machine to another machine. Also note that my username and machine name are different in this two. It looks like hashes are related to the username. Am I right? Is there a clean solution to get the project built on the offline machine?

- Gradle 4.0-bin
- com.android.tools.build 2.3.0

Comment: Solution: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-copy-gradle-caches-to-another-offline-machine/23413/2?u=abforce

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of directories that you can copy over to the offline machine:

```
$HOME/.gradle
$HOME/.android
$HOME/.m2
```

Along with the entire project that you have built. That will have a local `.gradle` directory as well.

Also make sure you have the android sdk m2 repo installed or make sure that you copy over the m2 repo for the support library found at `"https://maven.google.com"`

Comment: There's no `.m2` directory, but there are only `.gradle` and `.android`. Copied both of them, still it keeps giving the same error.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto are you copying over the entire project too?

Comment: Yes, entire project directory including that `.gradle`.

Comment: I think those hash strings are the main culprit.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto they could be and you are sure you do not have an `$HOME/.m2` directory? Those hashes should be md5 so they should be good to transfer over.

Comment: I double checked now. There's no such directory indeed.

Comment: Regarding hashes, md5 of what?

Comment: Sorry it is the shasum of the file. For example this path: ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep/0.5.2/63526b3c8b9638c21e9ced2f3b2963cde9d3c286 that hash is a shasum of the file firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep-0.5.2.aar So that should be the same for what you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149959/discussion-between-ray-hunter-and-hi-im-frogatto).

Answer (score 0):

As per [the official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:cache_copy), since at least version 6.1 of Gradle, it's possible to copy over the cache from the path `$GRADLE_HOME/caches/modules-<version>` to another machine for reuse. The only note is that the `*.lock` and `gc.properties` files from this directory should be skipped.